# What is sonic transition of an astrophysical fluid?

Tags: astrophysics

My notes mention *sonic transition of a fluid*. Is it where the speed of the fluid elements cross the speed of sound in the medium they are located?

Comment: Yes. It is the location where the mach number $M\equiv v/c_{\rm sound}=1$. Is there anything more specific you wish to ask?

Comment: Thank you, that's all.